# AHK A_tickcount inline update

Tags: autohotkey

Say I started a program timer using the following code in AHK:

```
start := A_TickCount
elapsedTime := A_TickCount - start
```

Is there a way I can update `elapsedTime` myself for offset adjusting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
F1::
start := A_TickCount
SetTimer, DetectElapsedTime, 1
return

    DetectElapsedTime:
elapsedTime := A_TickCount - start
ToolTip, %elapsedTime%
if (elapsedTime= "10000")   ; 10 seconds
{
    SetTimer, DetectElapsedTime, off    ; reset counter
    ; ToolTip
    Run, notepad ; do sth
}
return
```